# What does the different LWJGL OpenGL library numbers mean/do?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

For example, sometimes people use `GL15.SOME_VARIABLE` while `GL20` has the exact same variable. Do these libraries have any significant impact on how the program runs or is it just for organisation? Is it different version types and in that case what is the reason to use older versions over newer ones?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question

Answer (score 0):

Yes it differs but not in all, your question cannot have a direct answer as it's yes and no, Some of libraries do update the last ones or add up to them but u would use the older as they still have methods which are not repeated in the newer ones due to the no need for an edit

Answer (score 0):

The library numbers mean the version of OpengGL you use. For exemple `GL20.GL_VARIABLE` mean you use `OpenGL 2.0`.
Each version of OpenGL contains the attributes, functions and variable of the previous version. So for exemple `GL42.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is the exactly same variable as `GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`. Moreover if you look carefully at the code you will see that `GL42.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is not present in `GL42.class` but in `GL15.class`. So there is absolutely no difference between the two.
But it's stil recommended to use the most minimal version required for a feature because :

- One, for visibility, it's easier to understand the code.
- And most importantly, because not all graphics cards support recent versions of OpenGL. As well as some OS like MacOSX. It only supports up to OpenGL 4.1 ([Supported OpenGL version on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823)).
  While the latest version of OpenGL is 4.6